# Send request and wait for response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Is it possible in JS/php to send a request to a specific URL and then wait for responses from that URL?

I don't really know how to explain this question in a better way, but what I'm trying to do is to send a request to a page that has a queue on it and I want the request to "wait" on that page and send me a response as soon as it is through the queue.

Comment: So what did you tried ? and what are the issues you are facing with your solution

Comment: I don't even know how to do this. I thought that it might be possible to do it with jquery but i don't know how to get it to stay on the request page.

Comment: Take a look at [PHP - Curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: Or, for doing it on the client side, [jQuery.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

Comment: When you say "queue" do you mean something like "you're customer number X average wait time N minutes" kind of queue?

Comment: no it randomly let's you through. thanks for the suggestions i will look into them

Comment: @Peter curl was exactly what i needed. thank you!

Comment: @Peter or OP, would you add an answer below please?

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible.

When understanding you well, you send a request to a backend and want to wait for response until the queued process is finished. The process can (must not) take also a long time, like 5 minutes. 
And here is the problem, your request on backend will be closed after some time for **timeout** reasons.

The right way should be,

1. you send the request to your backend and get success response on successful queued request or failure on problems queuing your request.
2. After some time you can send second request to the backend to retrieve if the process has been done. This request can be send multiple times until all user queued request has been processed.

An other possible solution would be the usage of socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with AngularJS (javascript) for example.

With $http service you do :

```
$http.get('your_url').success(function(){
// Your code if there is a good response at your request
}).error(function(){
// Your code if you detected an error (page not found etc...)
})
```

Official Documentation from AngularJS : [$http Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Hope that it'll help :)

Answer (score 0):

with Jquery you can make an Ajax request to any other server side page in following way.

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

With PHP you've to make an `CURL` call to respective server-side file